# Infragistics SSResizer Control to Ressize Child Controls in Winforms

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, infragistics

Hello There,
            We had bought Infragistics SSResizer control back in 2003 for Vb. I was wondering if I can use it for C#.

My application changes its font size when you change the resolution which ultimately messes up the application. Any other solutions are appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

The SSResizer is a COM control built for use in Visual Basic and was never tested in any .NET environment so it isn't known whether this will work or not.  The recommendation is to replace the COM control with a .NET control and use that going forward.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Are there any free ones other than the above that I can use for .net environment? Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure what the specific functionality of the SSResizer was, maybe the Splitter would work: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.splitter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx